# Frontend development on Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, frontend

I really love the idea to use Docker so on the host computer I don't have any developlent stuff needed, like for frontend node, yarn/npm, for backend like nginx, php, mysql and then all the services like mailhog, redis etc. Just take any computer, install docker and this is like perfect zero config environment to start developing.

Although, I haven't seen too many good examples how to work like that.

And then I start to think, if it is even possible to have environment without dependencies on host, or it is just my crazy ideas. I want to hear some thought, some examples.

At the moment I've built docker-compose file with 3 VueJs frontend projects running my development command `command: sh -c 'yarn run serve'`, but if I check docker stats, I see that ram is 150mb for each container, and cpu usage - nothing. But the issue is that I hear my fans spinning too much when I run `docker-comose up -d`. I see that docker it self eats ~33% of CPU all the time on host.

Computer specs:

- MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)
- 2,8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
- 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3

Well, that's about it, maybe you have some good examples or suggestions.

One of the thing I haven't yet tried out is to not to run frontend containers when I run all the services, but spin them up only when neccessary when developing.

Answer (score 1):

I also use docker for development on my Mac, I had the same problems as you with excessive memory consumption. The solution I found was to add the flag :delegated to the volumes.

Read more about volumes [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/).

Or, you can use NFS:

[Set Up Docker For Mac with Native NFS](https://medium.com/@sean.handley/how-to-set-up-docker-for-mac-with-native-nfs-145151458adc)

[NFS With Docker on macOS Catalina](https://firehydrant.io/blog/nfs-with-docker-on-macos-catalina/)

[Revisiting Docker for Mac's performance with NFS volumes](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2020/revisiting-docker-macs-performance-nfs-volumes)

Comment: Thanks! I am using docker-sync for mac, but I haven't yet hoocked it up with frontend containers, but probably I shuold. Do you have any experience with that, or `delegated` flag works just fine and docker-sync is overkill?

Comment: I never used the docker sync, I use Docker Desktop. I work with about 15 projects that use a docker, 4 of them with VueJS. I was having problems with slowness and the solution I found was to add the flag: delegated to the volumes. As a result, performance increased by about 50%.